# Parsing a string into a Dataframe

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe

I have the following data

```
100///t1001///t2///t0.119///t2342342342///tHi\nthere!///n103///t1002///t2///t0.119///t2342342342///tHello
there!
1010///t10077///t2///t0.119///t2342342342///tHi\nthere!///n1044///t1003///t2///t0.119///t2342342342///tHello there!
```

In a file, I have multiple lines of of the above formatted data. Each line is delimited by `///n` and `///t`. For each line, there are four records that are delimited by `///n`. Inside each record, there are four columns that are delimited by `///t`. Now, I need to parse this into a Dataframe. So basically for the above two lines; since each line has 2 records with 6 columns; there should be 12 records in the Dataframe. Each record follows the same format.

I tried parsing this using a combination of split and amp but did not get the correct output

Answer (score 0):

You can process it using string transformations, like:

```
// Sample of input data
val str1 = "100///t1001///t2///t0.119///t2342342342///tHi\nthere!///n103///t1002///t2///t0.119///t2342342342///tHello there!"
val str2 = "1010///t10077///t2///t0.119///t2342342342///tHi\nthere!///n1044///t1003///t2///t0.119///t2342342342///tHello there!"

val df = Seq(str1, str2).toDF

// Process:
    val output = df.as[String].flatMap(row=>{
  val fields = row.split("///n").map(record=>{
    val fields = record.split("///t").toList
    (fields(0), fields(1), fields(2), fields(3), fields(4), fields(5))
  }).toList
  fields
}).toDF("column_1", "column_2", "column_3", "column_4", "column_5", "column_6")
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+------------+
|column_1|column_2|column_3|column_4|  column_5|    column_6|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+------------+
|     100|    1001|       2|   0.119|2342342342|   Hi       |
|                                              |there!      |
|     103|    1002|       2|   0.119|2342342342|Hello there!|
|    1010|   10077|       2|   0.119|2342342342|   Hi       |
|                                              |      there!|
|    1044|    1003|       2|   0.119|2342342342|Hello there!|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+------------+
```